# A system of three equations in three real variables

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the system of equations of three variables $(x_1, x_2, y)$ given by
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{9x_1}{\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}}+2yx_1&=-2\\
\frac{4x_2}{\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}}+2yx_2&=-1\\
x_1^2+x_2^2=1
\end{cases}.$$
Is it possible to find all solutions of this system?

I have made so many attempts but I still not be able to answer the question above. Any answer would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1=a$, $x_2=b$ and $y=c$.

If $c=0$ easy to show that it's impossible.

Also we see that $ab\neq 0$.

Thus, we have,
$$\frac{\frac{9a}{\sqrt{9a^2+4b^2}}+2}{\frac{4b}{\sqrt{9a^2+4b^2}}+1}=\frac{-2ac}{-2bc}$$ or
$$\frac{5ab}{\sqrt{9a^2+4b^2}}=a-2b, $$ which is homogeneous, but roots are very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

from the first and the second equation we get
$$9x_1+2yx_1\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}=2\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}$$
$$4x_2+2yx_2\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}=-\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}$$
from here we get
$$2yx_1\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}=2\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}-9x_1$$
$$2yx_2\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}=-\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}-4x_2$$
dividing both we get
$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{2\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}-9x_1}{-\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}-4x_2}$$
rearranging and squaring we get
$$0=15x_1^2x_2^2+9x_1^4+16x_2^4+36x_1^3x_2+16x_1^23x_2^3$$
dividing by $$x_1^2x_2^2\ne 0$$ we get
$$0=15+9\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2}+16\frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2}+36\frac{x_1}{x_2}+16\frac{x_2}{x_1}$$ now set $$\frac{x_1}{x_2}=t$$ good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: you can remove $y$ and find two equation and two variables from (1) and (2):

$$\left(\frac{9x_1}{\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}}+2yx_1\right)x_2 =-2x_2~~~~~(1)$$
$$\left(\frac{4x_2}{\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}}+2yx_2\right)x_1 =-x_1 ~~~~~~(2)$$
$$ x_1^2 + x^2 = 1 ~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$
$$(1) - (2)\Rightarrow \frac{5x_1x_2}{\sqrt{9x_1^2+4x_2^2}} = -2x_2+x_1 ~~~(4)$$

you can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ from (3) and (4) equations. Hence, found $y$ from the result.